# Adding a Cocos2D Scene on a UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios5

I want to run a cocos2D scene on a UIView, called **camera_view**.

So I try adding the camera_view to the openGLView :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView addSubview:cameraView];
```

And then push my scene, called **scene** :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: scene];
```

But after doing that, I can only see the UIView, and the cocos2D scene is no longer visible. However, before adding the camera_view as a subview of the openGLView, the scene was working absolutely fine.

How can I fix this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything drawn by Cocos2D is drawn directly on the EAGLView, not with views (as normally is with UIKit) but with OpenGL calls. So I think it is not possible to add subviews below any CCNode. I mean that the subviews will always appear above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is as follows :

I added my camera_view and the openGLView, each as a subview of the UIWindow :

```
[window addSubview: camera_view];
[window addSubView: [CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView];
```

Then I pushed the cocos2D scene :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: scene];
```

And that solved the problem. Now I can view the cocos2D scene on my UIView.